# Filtering events - SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently, I have:

```
public static IList getFilteredEvents(  DateTime Start, DateTime End, string env, string req) {
    string QueryString;
    if( env == "all" ) {
        QueryString = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '" + Start + "' AND '" + END + "'";
    } else {
        QueryString = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '" + Start + "' AND '" + END + "' AND env='" + env + "'";
    }
}
```

I am getting the request string by doing passing a data object from the view.  In my controller,  I get it like this:
`string env = Request.QueryString["filter"];`

Is there a better way to filter my results instead of having to write multiple queries in an if-elseif chain?  How would I achieve this for multiple filters e.g. in the query `AND req = '" + req + "';`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Unrelated, but it sounds to me like you are just asking for a SQL injection attack here.

Comment: This is just a bare example, but yes, I understand this is vulnerable to a SQL attack :].

Comment: The (in my opinion) definitive article on this is Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: lets try a different route here since these queries can get quite ugly. how many fields are we talking about filtering and move many rows? Other options are to query your data if the result set is small, and let a client side control handle the filtering. Telerik's free MVC grid for example does this automatically and allows users to sort, filter, etc quite easily. please please please convert this to parameters. if you need help on this let me know.

Comment: @AdamTuliper I am using the fullcalendar plugin to display the data and getting the value from a dropdown list to filter.  I might end up with 5 - 6 different dropdown lists and each time a dropdown item is selected, it should take into account the values of all the selected options.  Still haven't figured out a better way to solve this problem and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append `AND`s in `if-else`. For example,

```
 QueryString = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '" + Start + "' AND '" + END + "'";
 if ( env == "all")
 {        
    QueryString  += " AND (env IS NULL OR env=env)"; 
    //if env cannot be null, than you just need  " AND env=env"
 }
 else
 {
     QueryString += "' AND (env='" + env + "')";
 }
```

And it's better to use StringBuilder to build a dynamic string;

Answer (score 1):

You are really opening yourself up to SQL injection as per the comment. Hopefully you'd change this to a parameterised proc/do some validation on the values used.

Within the SQL you could then do:

```
AND (@env = 'all' OR env = @env)
```

If you insist on staying with dynamic SQL:

```
string envWhere = (env == "all") ? "" : " AND env = '" + env + "'";
```

Then concatenate this to the main SQL string